# Edit Ubuntu Details?

Tags: 13.04, ram, system-info

Long story short, I need to make it look like my computer has 2GB of Ram, instead of 4GB.  Is there a way I can edit a file or something, to make it change in the System Details?

Comment: Am curious to know the Long version of the Story.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to fork gnome-control-center, hard-code the 4GB value into it, and recompile. Or you could make a screenshot of your current System Details, photoshop 4GB over it, and write a small script that displays your new image over the regular window. I do NOT recommend either of these methods. You could be as creative as you like, but running out and buying an extra 2GB would be faster and safer in most cases.